# Get selected file/folder in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, wndproc

i need to customize the OpenFileDialog from the System.Win32 namespace (the modern 'Vista' dialog). I found good woorking articles how to do that using the old style dialogs from System.Windows.Forms namespace. The set up a NativeWindow and overload the WndProc method. When i do so with the file dialog from Win32 namespace, everything works fine (means i get all the notifications) expect geetting the WM_NOTIFY message when a file has been selected.

I discoverd additionally any child control of the file dialog using EnumChildWindows(...) and registered for WndProc/WM_NOTIFY but there is no CDN_TYPECHANGE notification

Is there a good way to get the notification about current selected files/folders from the System.Win32.OpenFileDialog class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Asc

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the new Vista file dialog is handled completely differently from the old-style XP file dialogs. You no longer deal with resource templates, window procedures etc.

Instead you use `QueryInterface` on the dialog interface to obtain an [`IFileDialogCustomize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775912.aspx) interface. Then you use its methods to customize the dialog. There are many examples available on the web. For instance, here's one from MSDN: [Common Item Dialog, Customizing the Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx#customizing). Most of the examples you will find are for C++, but since the API is COM based these are very easy to map over to C#.

Now, judging from your question, it is not so much customization as notification that interests you. In which case you need to look at the [`IFileDialogEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775876.aspx) interface. You can provide an implementation of that interface to the dialog, and then receive notification of various events, including folder and selection changes. Subscribe to the dialog's events by calling [`IFileDialog::Advise`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775948.aspx).

You'll probably find the interface translations found in the API CodePack to be very useful.